# EaselJS, drag and drop to container but click to child container

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent, shapes, easeljs

i have a little problem. i use easelJS to create some shape into an canvas.

i have create container class to stock circle shape with text on it. this class containe click function for the container.

i have created a other container class with a rectangular shape and a other text.

on this container, i have activate the drag and drop to move this into the canvas. that works fine, but, when i add the containers (circle shape) as a child of this container, the click function is call by the container with rectangular shape. 
i know that works like this because i have set the mousechildren at false.

if i change this properties, when i move the parent container, all children in it dont move with.

i want to redirect the click function parent, to the click function of my circle container.

in fact, i just need to create a shape moveable, with others shapes inside them clickable.

thx for your help, if you need my code, i can put this here

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't move a container without moving its children. This is literally what a container is... It is possibly you are moving contents of your container (a background?) and assuming that is the container itself? Can you post some code or a demo?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the pressmove of the container, and the mouse events on the children, since events in EaselJS bubble.

Here is a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/8L9wye4n/1/

```
// Listen for children events:
s.on("click", function(event) { event.target.scaleX = event.target.scaleY = event.target.scaleX+0.1 });

// Listen for container drag/drop
c.on("pressmove", function(event) {
    c.x = stage.mouseX; 
    c.y = stage.mouseY;
});
```

Hope that helps.